# Testing with a txt file

Tags: python

I created a input.txt file. There several sets of testing input date in input.txt. Then I run in the  terminal `python Filename.py <input.txt >output.txt`. After running I only get output of first set input date. How can I get all the output date automatically in output.txt?

```
# GET amount of money in bank
amount_in_bank = input( "How much money is in the bank? $" )
# GET amount of income
amount_of_income = input( "How much income is expected? $" )
# GET amount of expenses
amount_of_expenses = input( "How much money is going to be spent on    expenses? $" )
# CALCULATE money in bank + income - expenses
# SET amount available to result of previous calculation
amount_available = int( amount_in_bank ) + int( amount_of_income ) - int( amount_of_expenses )
# DISPLAY amount available
message = "Bobbie will have $" + str( amount_available ) + " left at the end of the month."
print ( message )
```

Comment: Share your python code

Comment: Your program (assuming that's all of it) does something once.  Where's the part where it does that thing _more than_ once?

Comment: Seems like you need a loop in the Python code, so it processes all the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you have not added any loop in order to traverse all the inputs in txt file. This might help:

Start with `fp = open('input.txt')`. Add a `for` loop like `for i, line in enumerate(fp.readlines()):` and then type the code you had added for getting the values and printing the message.